# Java: How to give unique ids and reuse them?

Tags: java, unique, identifier, reusability, finalize

I am implementing a simple class for giving ids to certain objects like this:

```
class idObject
{
  private static long next=0;
  private long id;

  idObject()
  {
     id=next;
     next = next +1;
  }

}
```

and derive all classes that I need my ids from this. The programm runs very long and a lot of objects are created. Thus, i am afraid next can overfow. Which results in non-unique ids. Some of the objects live very long, but most of them are deleted at some point. However, I would like to keep the ids unique.

My question is, is there an easy way, to reuse ids of the objects that are deleted? My idea was to create a list of free ids and add the id of an object when it dies. Originally, i am a C++ programmer, so I thought of using a destructer, which is obviously not available in Java. Is the finalize() method the correct choice in this situation?

Best Regards

Comment: For ultimate randomness and uniqueness and monitoring your objects still, look into `java.util.UUID`.

Comment: What's your use case exactly? Do you really expect to instantiate more than 2147483647 objects? Also you should read about concurrency because the code above is __not__ thread safe.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta 2,147,483,647 isn't the limit since a) 0 is a valid id, b) a negative id is possible and won't clash with a positive id, and c) the OP is using `long`, not `int`. There would need to be over 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 objects (circa 18 quintillion) before there would be a repeated id.

Comment: @DavidConrad sorry I didn't read thoroughly enough! Well more to my point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about running out of IDs, you can use UUIDs. There are 16^32 possible combinations of UUIDs and are randomly generated. If you want to be absolutely sure you don't have a collision with an existing ID, you can always keep a registry of created ones and make sure it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Hello and thank you all for the impressively fast answers!! I will use the UUID solution. Just for the sake of learning something: Why would I not use finalize() method to take care of it? Is there a reason or is it just not Javaish to do so?

Comment: finalize is not guaranteed to be called and shouldn't be used for resource cleanup. you can use it as a backup solution if you need to, but it's generally not a good idea to depend on finalize actually being called (or called when you think it will)

Answer (score 2):

Besides [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), you can also use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). With BigInteger, you can get sequential IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best solution is UUID class (mentioned by others), however it is randomly generated, hence it may be not unique and you will have to waste memory by keeping a list of already existing ids. So if you want to be sure that the id is unique, will not overflow and you do not waste memory you may want to use BigInteger class.

You should remember that if more than one thread creates objects you need to synchronize the code that generates ids, so you may need something like this:

```
class idObject
{
  private static BigInteger nextId = BigInteger.ZERO;
  private BigInteger id;

  private static synchronized BigInteger nextId() {
      BigInteger id = nextId;
      nextId = id.plus(BigInteger.ONE);
      return id;
  }

  idObject()
  {
     id = nextId();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be quite a feat to overflow a long by simply incrementing by one. A fast CPU may be able to overflow an int in about one second.

Overflowing a long takes 4 billion times as many increments - that is currently at least 4 billion seconds. Since a *year* has only about 30 million seconds, your program will need to run aproximately 133 years to overflow the long.

If the id is a transient id for objects in memory, a long should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Allocating 1,000,000 objects a second, you will run out of unique 64-bit identifiers sometime around the year 586,540 AD. Unless you need to persist these identifiers somewhere so they're unique between processes, I think you can safely use `long`.

Minor quibble with your code: your `idObject()` method is not thread-safe, and can return duplicate IDs if called from different threads at once. I would recommend using an `AtomicLong` to store the ID in this case.